# Wordpress post with no URL / viewable web page

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to configure a WP post so that it has no URL / viewable web page.  At that point it would essentially become a reusable content snippet that must be referenced elsewhere, from another page or post, but could not be linked to as its own page.

Thanks,

Keith

Comment: Should go to webmasters.se or wordpress.se

Comment: Going back to my question, does anyone know a way to disable presentation (being accessed as a web page) for a published post or page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-snippets/) seems to achieve what you want. Searching the [plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/plugins) with the term "Snippet" yielded this plugin.

You could also hack together something using custom page templates and pages.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the answer. You didn't necessarily answer my question as asked but this is a good solution for my current use case.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. Generally with wordpress it never hurts to check which plugins are available.